# How to run babel without inflating my package?

Tags: babeljs

I added babel to my project with 2 presets (es2015 and stage-0) and it added 100+ MB of dependencies to my node_modules folder.

Would it be possible to package only my transpiled code without babel dependencies, using a system-wide babel-cli? I tried installing this way but it errors:

```
Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "."
```

Comment: Are you using `npm3`? `npm2` doesn't flatten, which can be a huge issue for file size.

Comment: @loganfsmyth npm 3.10.8... the issue is that i could not get it to work without adding babel to my project node_modules and making it huge. i was expecting it wouldn't need to be there after transpiling

Comment: For me, running `npm i babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-es2016 babel-preset-stage-0` in an empty directory produces a `node_modules` folder that is 26MB, which is about what I'd expect. Perhaps someone in your dependencies is preventing npm from fully flattening the dependency graph? What is your `package.json`?

Comment: Any luck with this? I don't want to copy the preset to my folder, want to do it systemwide.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña i believe those are required in runtime... could not get it slim